# Why does Composer Install a Different Package?

Tags: php, magento, composer-php

I've been working with the Magento Firegento custom Composer installer, and I ran into this odd bit of Composer behavior I don't understand.

Consider the following dead simple `composer.json` file

```
{
    "require": {
        "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    }
}
```

If I run `compser.phar install` with this `composer.json` file, I get the following.

```
$ composer.phar install --no-dev 
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
  - Installing aoepeople/composer-installers (v0.0.1)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

From my mostly lay-person's understanding `composer.phar`, I've said

> Hey, composer, please install the `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` package from packagist.org

And composer has said back to me

> Sir, yes sir!  Here's the `aoepeople/composer-installers` package

I don't understand why composer installed `aoepeople/composer-installers`, when I asked for `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer`.

To be clear: I understand the reason `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` wasn't installed is this is a package that lives in a [different composer repository](http://packages.firegento.com/).  My original mistake was not including this repository in my `composer.json` file.

**However**, it doesn't make sense to me that composer would install a different package than the one I asked for.  When I [search packagist there's no `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` extension](https://packagist.org/search/?q=magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer).

Why does packagist install a different extension?  What's happening behind the scenes to make `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` resolve to `aoepeople/composer-installers`?  How/where in the composer source could I debug this sort of thing myself in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vinai published a great writeup on Magento and Composer [here](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/composer-with-magento/).

Quoting from there

> Composer will use packagist.org to look where to get the libraries. Because Magento modules aren’t listed there, you will have to add the packages.firegento.org repository to the configuration as follows [...]

So you will need the repository

```
   "repositories":[
     {
       "type":"composer",
       "url":"http://packages.firegento.com"
     }
   ],
```

to get the magento composer installer.

And yes composer offers replacements. On the packaging entry for [aoepeople/composer-installers](https://packagist.org/packages/aoepeople/composer-installers) you will notice the replaces section:

[image: Package Screenshot]

And since `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` is not available on packagist composer will deliver you `aoepeople/composer-installers`.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so that's a weird behavior :) I'm the author of the *aoepeople/composer-installers* package and the idea behind this is that this package provides an alternative (very basic and simplified implementation of the composer package-type `magento-module` - and adds another type `magento-source`. I only want the installer to put the package in the right place - keeping it simple. That's why I decided to come up with an alternative package.

The reason why the *aoepeople/composer-installer* replaces the *magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer* is because many Magento modules already come with a composer.json that requires the *magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer*. In order to be able to seamlessly use the simpler installer that one is "pretending" to be the hackathon-installer. But unless you actively require *aoepeople/composer-installers* in your project's composer.json you should continue using the original installer as no Magento module's composer.json out there (not even ours) is directly referring to *aoepeople/composer-installers*.

The fact that packagist tries to be "smart" and returns a package that replaces a package that's not registered is new to me and - to be honest - very disturbing. While this might be intended behavior I share the opinion that this could easily be abused. I start liking Alan's idea to bypass packagist completely using `"packagist":"disabled"`. Especially in the case of Magento modules this seems to happen easily because most of the Magento modules are unknown to packagist while being registered at packages.firegento.com only.

A simple quickfix/workaround to this specific situation could be to register *magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer* on packagist.org.

Answer (score 1):

The Packagist package at https://packagist.org/packages/aoepeople/composer-installers has metadata saying that it replaces the magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer package. Packagist would then install this as it's the package that replaces what you asked for.

Docs here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace